# Postgresql: optimize select query with multiple count case columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to come up with solution to my problem which I'm going to explain in the following sentences.

I need to count employees at each department that worked during certain year. Let's say 'Table' is a joined table that includes all needed info (employees' ids, department they work at, dates of start and end of them working for the company and so on).
Assume we have such a query:

```
select department_name,
       count(
             case 
             when employee.date_start <= '2018-01-01' and employee.date_end >= '2018.12.31'
             then 1 end) as emp2018, 
       count(
             case 
             when employee.date_start <= '2019-01-01' and employee.date_end >= '2019.12.31'
             then 1 end) as emp2019, 
       count(
             case 
             when employee.date_start <= '2020-01-01' and employee.date_end >= '2020.12.31'
             then 1 end) as emp2020
from Table
group by department_name;
```

I need those numbers in columns such as

| Department | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dep1 | 109 | 112 | 110 |
| Dep2 | 88 | 89 | 92 |
| ... | .. | .. | .. |

And so on... And I thought may be there is something that could help me to circumvent those repetitive counts in select, so the script is nice and not that large when there is a need of much more years. Is there anything to do about it?

Hope I explained it well and thank you in advance!

Comment: You can simplify your CASE expressions to `count(*) filter (where extract(year from date_start) = 2018)` but there is no way to avoid writing one expression for each output column you want

Comment: could you use crosstab? https://ubiq.co/database-blog/create-pivot-table-postgresql/

Comment: you could wirte a view with the coluns: department, year, and count
But, if you want the result with year as coluns you need to repeat the columns or see the crosstab funcion as Bryan said above
And if you do this hardcoded you'll need to change your query every year.